# Setting FlowDirection to RightToLeft for all windows in an application

Tags: window, right-to-left

I am trying to set the `FlowDirection` of all the windows the application will generate to `RightToLeft`. I tried the following

```
Window.FlowDirectionProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(Window),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
    ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight));
```

I am doing this before I initialize any Window class.

But with this, I get `TypeInitializerException` whenever I initialize a Window class.

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'System.Windows.Window' threw an exception. --->
> System.ArgumentException: PropertyMetadata is already registered for
> type 'Window'.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how I could change my code to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `static FlowDirection` property to your app

```
static property Windows::UI::Xaml::FlowDirection FlowDirection{ 
Windows::UI::Xaml::FlowDirection get() ; };
```

Then call next line in constuctor of application pages:

```
this->FlowDirection = App::FlowDirection;
```